# Pyspark Delete rows in table one which matches rows in table two

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

#### Problem Statement

Here's my use case:
I have 2 tables, `Today_data` and `Yesterday_data`, for example:

Today_data:

```
Id    Value
1     1_data
2     2_data
3     3_data
```

Yesterday_data:

```
Id    Value
2     2_data
4     4_data
8     8_data
```

I want to delete `Today_data` df rows if the row matches `Yesterday_data` row.

#### Expected Result

```
Id    Value
1     1_data
3     3_data
```

#### Approach Taken

I was thinking it should be a easy left join where `Today_data` will be on the left, however after I read through all the join operations in pyspark here: https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-join-explained-with-examples/#pyspark-join-types, I don't see any of them can solve my problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `left_anti` join:

```
today_df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, "1_data"), (2, "2_data"), (3, "3_data")], ["Id", "Value"])
yesterday_df = spark.createDataFrame([(2, "2_data"), (4, "4_data"), (8, "8_data")], ["Id", "Value"])

result = today_df.join(yesterday_df, ["Id"], "left_anti")

result.show()
#+---+------+
#| Id| Value|
#+---+------+
#|  1|1_data|
#|  3|3_data|
#+---+------+
```

This one is explained in [this section](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-join-explained-with-examples/#pyspark-left-anti-join) of the link you provided.